# Delete products from my account

Tags: magento-1.9

We are displaying Products in My account section . now we are trying to **delete** the product once we click on "Delete" button.

I used 2 ways to find solution :

**1st way** : After using below code, once i  click on "Delete" button, **all products are deleting** instead of one product :

[image]

```
<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>
       <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

        <?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product)
        {
        echo $product->getName().' <br>';
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());    

        ?>

    <form 
    action="<?php      
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    try
     {
    $product->delete();
    Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) { }

    ?>" method="post">  

    <div>   
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>  
    </div>
    </form>

   <?php
        }
    ?>
```

**update**

**2nd way** : using **controller** to delete product , now onclick button, its redirect to url : `sitename.com/example/amasty/deleteproduct?itemId=` but not deleting product.

```
public function deleteproductAction()
    {

        $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('itemId');
        if($itemId) 
        {
            Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();           
           $this->_redirectReferer();
        }           

    }
```

**html**

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
 ?>
<a href="#" onclick="return deleteItem('<?php $_product; ?>');">Delete</a>
```

**script**

```
function deleteItem(itemId) {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) {          
           window.location = '<?php echo $this->getUrl();?>example/amasty/deleteproduct?itemId=' + itemId;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: i followed link : https://sarfarazlaghari.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/magento-how-to-delete-magento-product-from-frontend-code/

Comment: i also tried `<a href = "<?php Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
try
 {
$product->delete();
Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
} 
catch(Exception $e) 
{
echo "write";
}

?>">
<button><span><span>Delete</span></span></button>
</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code.

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId()); ?>
<a href="#" onclick="return deleteItem('<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>');">Delete</a>
```

And

```
public function deleteproductAction()
{
    $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('itemId');
    if($itemId) 
    {
        Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
        $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($itemId);
        $_product->delete();
        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }           

}
```

Comment: Updated your code, now onclick button its redirecting to `sitename.com/example/amasty/deleteproduct?itemId=` , but product not deleting..... please check......

Comment: Try replacing `deleteItem('<?php $product->getId() ?>')` with `deleteItem('<?php $_product->getId() ?>')`

Comment: sorry, still the same......

Comment: Ohh.. yes. I got the error.  replace `deleteItem('<?php $product->getId() ?>')` with `deleteItem('<?php echo $product->getId() ?>')`

Comment: okay, now i got : `Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area.` error

Comment: Please check with updated code. @vickeycolors

Comment: even i was also trying with `Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);` , but i was trying in phtml file , a big fool i'm :) thanks a ton....